# Insert Multiple Values to Database using Single TextBox ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one of the tables with the attributes: id, class name, student name. I want to enter data 1 class name with many student names with 2 textboxes. 1 Textbox is used for class names, 1 textbox for student names. For the student's name textbox, I enter names by separating them with "," each name. How to overcome this problem? Are there other ways to fix this problem? thanks.

Model Classroom.cs

```
public partial class Classroom
{
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string class_name { get; set; }
        public string student_name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem you are facing? You need to split the Text of StudentName textbox by "," , that will give you array of student names. Loop thru the array and execute insert query for all the studentnames.

Comment: You need to design your model in a way that will adhere to your required functionality. You can have something like a `List<Classroom>` defined in a view-model that will hold the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `YourStringName.split(",")` this will return you a String Array with your values you had seperated with your comma but it is very dirty. I would Prefer to use for each Student a singel button click that adds the student to a list of Classroom and add them together to database.